# WebServiceException: Method Parameter: <foo> cannot be null. This is BP 1.1 R2211 violation

Tags: web-services, parameters, null, glassfish, webmethod

Recently I migrated my application from jboss5.1 to Glassfish 3.1.2. Despite other problems I`ve found, now I cannot pass a null parameter to my web method anymore. And it was not a problem in Jboss. What should I do? Is there a flag to allow null parameter through my web melhod.
(My application uses icefaces3.0.1 and JSF 2.0; the WS is a EJB project, also in the same server for now) tks

error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method Parameter: toDate cannot be null. This is BP 1.1 R2211 violation.
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing did get discussed here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-128

> JAX-WS 2.0 enforces strict Basic Profile 1.1 compliance. The following
>   are known cases where .NET framework does not enforce strict BP 1.1
>   semantics and their usage can lead to interoperability problems.

Also at Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/DataBinding7.html

Not quite sure when but I think I had the same problem when migration from Tomcat 5 to 6